# Using the "net user" command in Windows XP to list all group memberships for a specific Active Directory user

Tags: windows-xp, active-directory

Is it possible to list all group memberships for a certain AD user?
I thought it was something like:

```
net user londondom\john
```

But this doesn't seem to work for AD users.  The same command will work for local users though:

```
net user johnlocal
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try the following. I think it only works on the currently logged-in domain:

```
net user john /domain
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was trying it with the domain group before the username and it didn't like it.

Answer (score 4):

Write all direct groups for the account

```
dsquery user -samid loginname | dsget user -memberof >> groups.txt
```

List all group for the login account, additionally show nested groups(recursive)

```
dsquery user -samid loginname | dsget user -memberof -expand
```

Comment: `dsquery`/`dsget` absent here (WinXP). Any specific packages needed?